# Database backup with cron job

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I created a backup.sh in /var/www/cronjobs/ where every other cronjobs are:

```
mysqldump --user root --password=mypass12--opt MYDATABASE \
    > /home/balint/db/db-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql
```

in the /etc/crontab I specified the cron just like my other cronjobs:

```
*/2 * * * * root wget -q -O- http://mydomain.com/cronjobs/backup.sh
```

Not a single file is created in /home/balint/db/
I created the db folder manually. And I can enter mysql and phpmyadmin with the user root and the password mypass12. The */2 is for testing only, of course.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `wget` command will get the script from `mydomain.com`, but it does not execute it. So it is no surprise that it's acting as if the script is not being run, because it isn't.

**added in response to comment:**

If "all your cronjobs" are written like that and are working, then you are using some non-standard `cron` which you didn't tell us about. 
I just tested a job in `/etc/crontab` as you described on Ubuntu 13.04. It behaved as documented and didn't pass the stdout of the `cmd` portion of the job as input to another shell.

Have you looked in `/var/log/syslog` for any diagnostics?

Comment: I use the wget command with all my cronjobs and they are all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all backup your mysql dump using the command in the backup script.

```
mysqldump --user root --password=mypass12--opt MYDATABASE > /home/balint/db/db-`$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")`.sql
```

and then append it with scp to transfer being generated to the remote location

```
scp /home/balint/db/db-`$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")`.sql you@yourip
```

for a passwordless login make sure to add the public key of the machine in the remote machine where you want to upload the database dump see the below link

[SSH passwordless login](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)